# How to display seconds in DateTime field in MS Dynamics CRM 2013

Tags: datetime-format, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have created an entity and added a DateTime field on the form. When I open the form and manipulate with DateTime field, seconds are not present. In CRM configurations, I can see only HH:MM part and not seconds.

Can anyone please help to resolve the same?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is to develop webresource that will display datatime value with seconds.